# Why does Metamsk display the sign data as unicode question marks and other various characters when signing a message with Viem?

Tags: solidity, metamask, signature, ecrecover, viem

I'm trying to sign a message in [Viem](https://viem.sh/docs/actions/wallet/signMessage.html) and recover the signer in Solidity, it works as expected, however, the Metamask pop-up window displays the data to be signed incorrectly.

[image]

#### Here is my Viem ts code:

```js
const signature = await walletClient.signMessage({
        message: { raw: "0xe4A98D2bFD66Ce08128FdFFFC9070662E489a28E" as `0x${string}` },
      });
     console.log("signature:", signature);
     // signature: 0x09a180eb5c1ab7914a811f5e216ac3741a1501d001497446c7ced23f3c72fd9f457cbbba457bcd514bb593b99b3ff52ab2f8e17042b600f1a6e54d9f32b33b041c
```

#### Here is my Solidity code that recovers the address correctly

First when given the address from above as input:

```js
function getAddressHashedMsg(address input) public pure returns (bytes32 messageHash) {
        messageHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", "20", input)
        );    
    }
```

returns `0xf5b59420194a3cbe3e9f66c88c83b61ab6979585c19e8a7652a8791d85e705f2`

When given the hash from `getAddressHashedMsg()` and the signature from Viem:

```js
    /**@notice Returns an address for an inputted signed message and signature */
    function recoverSigner(
        bytes32 _ethSignedMessageHash,
        bytes memory _signature
    ) public pure returns (address) {
        (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) = splitSignature(_signature);

        return ecrecover(_ethSignedMessageHash, v, r, s);
    }
```

This returns `0xe4A98D2bFD66Ce08128FdFFFC9070662E489a28E` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, viem's `signMessage` works by [calling the `personal_sign` JSON-RPC method](https://viem.sh/docs/actions/wallet/signMessage.html#json-rpc-methods) on the wallet (in this case, MetaMask). When MetaMask receives a `personal_sign` request, it will **represent the bytes as a UTF-8 string** to the end-user. This is because `personal_sign` is intended to be used with human-readable string messages and not raw byte arrays.

As [noted in the MetaMask documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/sign-data/#use-personal_sign):

> important
>
> - Don't use this method to display binary data, because the user wouldn't be able to understand what they're agreeing to.

So the questions marks and other characters in the dialog are simply the result of MetaMask interpreting the bytes of the address as a UTF-8 string. You can reproduce the logic using this JavaScript:

```js
const byteString = '0xe4A98D2bFD66Ce08128FdFFFC9070662E489a28E';
const byteArray = Uint8Array.from(byteString.substring(2).match(/.{2}/g), v => parseInt(v, 16));
const utf8 = new TextDecoder().decode(byteArray);
// '䩍+�f�\b\x12����\x07\x06b䉢�'
```

If you wanted the message `0xe4A98D2bFD66Ce08128FdFFFC9070662E489a28E` to appear in the MetaMask dialog, you must instead request a `personal_sign` on the bytes representing this string. In viem, you can do this by directly passing a string to `message`, instead of passing it through the `raw` attribute:

```js
const signature = await walletClient.signMessage({
    message: "0xe4A98D2bFD66Ce08128FdFFFC9070662E489a28E"
});
```

The corresponding Solidity would also need to be updated to hash a string of the address, and not the address literal.

Comment: So if my solidity function takes an address as input, I would be forced to convert it to a string? Also, if I only want to hash a single address, would it be overkill to use EIP 712?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to convert the `address` to a `string` representing the address. Note that the `len(message)` would also need to be updated from `"20"` to `"42"` to reflect the number of bytes the string takes. As for EIP-712, I think this would depend on your overall use case/intent; [MetaMask's documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/sign-data/) has good explanation on the pros and cons of both approaches.